# Passing async storage data to react navigation drawer component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have some profile info data like name,email and mobile no in my app drawer in my react native app. I want to pass data to the custom app drawer component when the user logs in from async storage. Basically the problem is to pass async storage data to a functional component.

```js
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator ({
  Home: {
    screen : Maps,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      title: `Search by`
    })
  },
  Vendor: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      title: `Vendor List`,
    })
  },
  Notifications: NotificationsScreen,
  Events: SearchDetails,
  Venue : {
    screen: SearchScreen,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      title: `Venue Availability`,
    })
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsScreen
  }
}, {
  drawerPosition: 'left',
  contentComponent: customDrawerContentComponent,
  drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
  drawerCloseRoure: 'DrawerClose',
  drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
  drawerWidth: 320,
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#fff',
    inactiveTintColor: '#030303',
    activeBackgroundColor: '#B90066',
    inactiveBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    itemsContainerStyle: {
      marginHorizontal: 10
    },
    itemStyle: {
      height: 40,
      borderRadius: 60,
    },
    activeLabelStyle: {
      fontSize: 20, 
      fontWeight: 'normal'
    }
  }
  })
  
  const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  AuthLoadingScreen: AuthLoadingScreen,
  Auth: AuthStackNavigator,
  App: {
    screen: AppDrawerNavigator
  }
})


const WeTaAppDrawer = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator)

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <WeTaAppDrawer />
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can i pass login user name, email etc to that drawer component? That is my question.

Comment: Why do you need to pass the data to customDrawerContent.... You can have access to the storage in your drawer

Comment: can you show me how can i pass data to the drawer component by accessing storage of the drawer? @Sarmad

Comment: Are you using AsyncStorage?

Comment: Yes i am @Sarmad

Answer (score 1):

You can use the componentDidMount in customDrawerContentComponent component and get the user data from asyncStorage like

```
async componentDidMount(){
  const user = await AsyncStroage.getItem('user);
  this.setState({ user });
}
```

then you can use the state in your render method